# SearchView queryHint doesn't show when focusing on the view automatically when activity starts

Tags: android, focus, searchview

I have an activity that starts with the SearchView focused on it. The thing is, I have a queryHint for the SearchView that does not show when entering the activity, it shows only after typing and deleting something. I need to show this information out from the starts because it is critical that the user is being aware of what written (case sensitivity issues)

here is my SearchView -

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/activity_search_explore_search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:queryHint="Search - (Case Sensitive)"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
```

here the java code that gets it's focus -

```
mSearchView.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, b) -> mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search - (Case Sensitive)"));
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setFocusable(true);
    mSearchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add below line in your SearchView.

```
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
app:queryHint="Search - (Case Sensitive)"
```

Comment: Thank you. for some reason the "app" for 'app:iconifiedByDefault' was not autocomplete, so I had to manually write it down. Do you know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: because this namesapace is required xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"